# Chrome loading image on drag even with preventDefault() in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I'm having issues with an angular directive not preventing the default chrome action.

here's my directive

```
app.directive('fileDrag', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('drop', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e);
        return false;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And my html

```
<div style="width: 500px; height:500px; background-color: red;" file-drag></div>
```

I can't seem to get Chrome to not load the image in a new tab when dragging onto the element. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also `preventDefault` on the `dragover` event, So change your code to this:

```
app.directive('fileDrag', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('drop', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e);
        return false;
      });
      elem.bind('dragover', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  };
});
```